# Outlook 2016 crashing (riched20.dll)

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016, microsoft-office-2016

Outlook 2016 (v1609 build 7369.21.20) keeps crashing while being used.
The Event Viewer reveals:

> Faulting application name: OUTLOOK.EXE, version: 16.0.7369.2120, time
>   stamp: 0x58bf7ba8 Faulting module name: riched20.dll, version:
>   0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x58bac1cd Exception code: 0xc0000005 Fault offset: 0x0000a916 Faulting process id: 0x1d94 Faulting application
>   start time: 0x01d2b38ba56df461 Faulting application path: C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE Faulting module
>   path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft
>   Shared\Office16\riched20.dll Report Id:
>   db2987a2-1f95-11e7-b766-28d244394268 Faulting package full name: %14
>   Faulting package-relative application ID: %15

Is there any way to fix this issue? 
Thank you

Comment: You have Windows system file corruption, sfc /scannow, will solve the problem.  If your using Windows 8+ use DISM instead

Comment: @Ramhound The scan did not find any integrity violations unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

I experienced this issue when browsing folders with more than 10000 items. Work around is to group mail into sub-folders (previous years etc). HTH.

Comment: Your answer is like a comment, it is a good idea but you did not provide a solution for OP

Answer (score 1):

1. Scan your system for malware and spyware.
2. Go to “%windir%\system32\” and check whether these 2 files exist: riched20.dll, riched32.dll.

If they do, please open a command prompt with administrator privilege and run the following command to re-register them:

Regsvr32 %windir%\system32\riched20.dll /i
Regsvr32 %windir%\system32\riched32.dll /i

After 1 and 2, if the problem persists, reinstall/use repair option for Office so the .dlls are actually replaced with default ones.